# Error no. -4094 when running React Native on Windows

Tags: react-native

So prior to using Windows, I've made a few projects on Mac.
After I `git clone` some of these projects on Windows, I get the following message when running `react-native start` in the respective project roots, making it unable to run.

`ERROR  UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\Naoto\Documents\foo\node_modules\.bin\cdl'
{"errno":-4094,"code":"UNKNOWN","syscall":"lstat","path":"C:\\Users\\Naoto\\Documents\\foo\\nod
e_modules\\.bin\\cdl"}
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\Naoto\Documenst\foo\node_modules\.bin\cdl'
    at Error (native)`

From what I gather, the command `lsat` is missing?

No search results with the exact error number showed up, but running `react-native init Foo2` seems to be fine. Permission issue?

Comment: Any chance your `node_modules` folder has been pushed to your git repository? The `node_modules\.bin` folder has a bunch of symbolic links that might get messed up if they're just copied. If the `node_modules` was cloned from your repo, then remove it, run `npm install`, and try again.

Comment: @YSK I wish that was the case but in my `.gitignore` I have `node_modules/` written out... might try wiping `node_modules` entirely and see what happens.

Comment: If this still fails, next thing I'd do (given that Googling seems to offer no help) is run SysInternals' [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what react/node are trying to do, and what error they're hitting. It's a big hammer, but can help track this down.